# Need for AINR-based simulations (vs. laboratory experimentation)

Tags: computational-chemistry, ab-initio

The Results section of this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1021/acscentsci.9b00520) related to *ab initio* molecular dynamics states that "16 $\ce{H_2O}$ and 15 $\ce{HCN}$ molecules were taken together, and the system was allowed to evolve for 750 ps" in order to find pathways for RNA precursors. The question might be naive but, what is the need of such a complex and expensive simulation if water and hydrogen cyanide can be mixed in the laboratory and study what results from this homogeneous mixture? Is it environmental conditions, or the temporal resolution of the study what matters here?

Comment: Your question might be better suited for matter modeling SE, as they might provide input into what makes simulations grand as opposed to experiments. Simulations, if accurate (always arguable), provide information about events at the molecular level that would be hard and even more expensive to obtain by experimental means. They might also stimulate experiments (to verify what is predicted by the sims). Theory sometimes leaps ahead of experiments.

Comment: RNA precursors need catalyzers to let HCN and H2O react.